# Simple Web Application for Embedded Device

Tags: linux, apache, frameworks, embedded

I have an embedded device running a full version of Debian. I need to create a web accessible application that resides on the device which manages the entries in my application's configuration file on the device. Think of it as a UI for my console application.

Since the device runs Debian I can use the Apache server along with Python, Perl, PHP, etc. However, I am fairly new to the Apache/Linux world and was wondering what the best way to design this application would be.

For instance, if I am hosting a website on the device should the web app just call a CGI running on the device that goes off onto the Linux OS and updates my settings. I know there's probably not one right way to do it. I just don't want to do it the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an uncommon problem (in web development circles) so there's no real 'wrong way'. I've done it in the past with thttpd and a custom CGI script (written in C); this was a great solution as it took very little flash space.

It sounds like you've got a lot of resources (memory and disk) to play with, so something like [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com) may save you some dev time.

Comment: I am using a combination of thttpd and Python CGI. My scope is pretty limited so Webmin was a bit overkill but it might provide useful on future projects.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Morfik](http://www.morfik.com).

Answer (score 0):

There is no "correct" way and you will get a thousand responses from different people.

If you have lot of resources just use Apache and a CGI in Python. This is the quick, easy but not very secure solution.

If performance is a problem and resources are limited use WT as Duck suggested.

Also you should perform a search on embedded/Debian/linux sites/forums because somebody might have already created exactly what you need ( = 0 effort for you)